# How to change the position of a dialog?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have created a dialog in Libgdx main menu screen.

I have tried

```
dialog.setPosition(300, 300);
dialog.show(stage);
```

It doesn't do anything. Is it a camera trick? Am I missing something?

Comment: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Dialog.html#show-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage say that dialog is centered by default with show method. Maybe try an stage.addActor(dialog) instead of show method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case some people encounter the same issue :

---

[Libgdx javadoc](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Dialog.html#show-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage) says dialog is centered by default with show method.

Do :

```
dialog.setPosition(300, 300);
stage.addActor(dialog);
```

Instead of `dialog.show`to let the dialog use these positions instead of default ones computed by show method.

Comment: is there a chance you could answer this, since you seem to have good knowledge of libgdx http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/137562/libgdx-aligning-buttons-inside-dialog

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `show` method:

```
dialog.show(stage, sequence(Actions.alpha(0), Actions.fadeIn(0.4f, Interpolation.fade)));
dialog.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
```

According to the source code, the general `show` method just auto-sets the position to the center. By using this method, you could pass the auto-set center.

Comment: Welcome to GameDev! Please note that I have removed the part about "this is already answered, but.."; that does not really matter, in context. We like other answers that might cater to other users. If you have a good alternate answer, feel free to post it, even if the question already has an accepted answer! You might even get more votes than the original.