# Libgdx: Aligning buttons inside dialog

Tags: java, android, libgdx, ios

I have the following dialog, semi circle shape. I want to position  buttons in it.

[image]

```
        dialog.button(closeButton, false);
        dialog.getContentTable().add(buttonS);
        dialog.getContentTable().add(button);
        dialog.getContentTable().add(hwTo);
```

The only way I am able to move a button is by using for a example

```
    dialog.getContentTable().add(hwTo).pad(300);
```

But I don't want to pad anything, since it affects other buttons, I tried `align`, `button.setPosition` and whatnot, nothing works.

I was told to remove the table and ise Custom WidgetGroup. I removed the table, still having the same problem, nothing works except padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dialog extends from Group, which means you can do `dialog.addActor(myActor)`. Using addActor, you have a full control of the actor positions. You should go this way.

Comment: could you please answer this http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/138303/libgdx-resizing-images-correctly or http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/138339/clicklisteners-not-working-correcly-conflicting or http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/138301/libgdx-how-to-setzindex-for-pause-dialog