# Libgdx: How to setZIndex for pause dialog?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, ios

Pause dialog has to appear on top of the play screen, it has to appear on top of other objects.

I have tried to use

```
dialog.setZIndex(10); // or whatever number and I tried adding it in many places
```

It just doesn't work, how to make the dialog be on top of other objects? for a ccomplete version [here](http://pastebin.com/yZ8ssvkp)

I'm using only one batch and the stage is used only to add background and dialog

```
  stage = new Stage();
  Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
  stage.addActor(bg); // somewhere else in the code
  stage.addActor(btnPause);
  camera.update();
  game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
  stage.act(delta);
  stage.draw(); // and thats about it for stage
  game.batch.begin();
  font.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
  font.draw(game.batch, myScore + score, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), camY);
  // and here I draw the game   game.batch.draw(game) and I'm using only one batch
```

I hope I didn't miss anything

If I put the game batch in state.RUN in an effort to hide objects when the pause dialogue appears, then when I resume, it will go to batch.end and exit the game

Pause

```
public void pause() {
 this.state = State.PAUSE;
 final Dialog dialogP = new Dialog("", skin, "pauseDialog") {};

 dialogP.setScale(4, 6);
 dialogP.setPosition(Align.center, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());


 dialogP.addAction(sequence(alpha(0),
  parallel(fadeIn(.5 f)),
  moveBy(0, -1000 f, .30 f, Interpolation.smooth),
  moveBy(0, 30 f, .40 f, Interpolation.smooth)));

 //PlayOn
 ImageButton btnPlayOn = UIFactory.createButton(txtrPlayOn);
 btnPlayOn.setSize(40, 40);
 btnPlayOn.setPosition(75, 75, Align.center);
 dialogP.addActor(btnPlayOn);

 //EndGame
 ImageButton btnEndGame = UIFactory.createButton(txtrEndGame);
 btnEndGame.setSize(40, 40);
 btnEndGame.setPosition(75, 55, Align.center);
 dialogP.addActor(btnEndGame);

 stage.addActor(dialogP);


 //playOnAction
 btnPlayOn.addListener(new ClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
   dialogP.hide();
   resume();
  }
 });


 //EndGameAction
 //PlayButtonAcion
 btnEndGame.addListener(
  new InputListener() {
   @Override
   public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
    super.enter(event, x, y, pointer, fromActor);

    Actions.scaleTo(0.7 f, 0.7 f, 0.5 f, Interpolation.bounceOut);
    stage.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.moveBy(-stage.getWidth(), 0, .5 f), Actions.run(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
      game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
     }
    })));

   }

  });


}
```

The basic principle is implemented from the accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576181/pause-resume-a-simple-libgdx-game-for-android)

Comment: What does the `draw` method look like for the thing that renders the dialog? Are you using more than one `Stage`, are you using more than one `Batch` are you using the same `Batch` more than once in a single update?

Comment: @bornander please read my edit

Comment: What does the code look like where you add the `Dialog` to the `Stage`?

Comment: @bornander please read my edit